# What if there are more than one my.cnf files on my server?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

What if there are more than one `my.cnf` files on my server?

Which configuration file will be looked by MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming one runs mysql under linux, there the option-files will be read in that order:

- the file specified by option `--defaults-file=/PATH/TO/my.cnf` while startup of mysqld
- `/etc/my.cnf`
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- `SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf` (usually sysconfdir is `/etc`)
- `$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf`
- the path set by  `--defaults-extra-file=/PATH/TO/my.cnf`
- `~/my.cnf` (your homedir, usually used for mysql-client configuration)

Also keep in mind that there are three options which change this behavior in MySQL:

- `-defaults-file=/PATH/TO/my.cnf` - only read that option-file
- `-defaults-extra-file=/PATH/TO/myextra.cnf` - read all global option-files, then this
- `-no-defaults` - ignore every option-file and start with default

Please also refer to the docs on option-files: [MySQL-Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html)

Answer (score -1):

The one specified on the command line that starts the mysqld process, or if no configuration file is specified, the default location.  On Linux it is in `/etc`. I don't know where the Windows default is, but you can look in the documentation.